# After installing ubuntu my pc still boots straight to windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I installed ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1 and everything went fine with the installation.  I followed this guide http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html almost perfectly, except I didn't create a /home partition and I forgot to turn fast boot off till after the install.

After installing, I don't get an option to boot ubuntu upon startup.  If I hold down shift when I restart from windows and click 'use a device' it gives me a ubuntu option, and if I go to Boot Manager ubuntu is listed in the Boot Options Menu, but it boots straight to windows otherwise.  In UEFI Settings ubuntu isn't even listed as a boot option.  I tried running boot-repair but it didn't help.  Secure Boot has been off the entire time.

I can access ubuntu now from windows, but it's a pain not having the option when I boot the computer.

Comment: You have to select which OS to boot in your bios

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode or BIOS boot mode? May be best to post the link to the Boot-Repair summary report.

Answer (score 0):

Boot again from your Ubuntu Live USB and open GParted. Set the boot flag to your Ubuntu partition.

This will result in using GRUB2 as boot loader, which is installed on your Ubuntu's partition. When the boot flag is set to the Windows partition, it will use Windows' boot loader.

Comment: Grub does not use boot flag. And if UEFI system, gparted uses boot flag to know which partition is the efi partition and that is required for UEFI boot to work. Using boot flag only works with BIOS where you keep a Windows boot loader in the MBR and install grub to partition, which is not normally suggested.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised that it has to do with GRUB.  Reinstall your GRUB on master drive after you instealled both OS, which forces GRUB to detect BOTH OS, and configure itself (be sure to reboot).

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

To boot Ubuntu OS, go to the bios setting of your pc and then select Ubuntu from there , save the changes.
work is done and now restart your pc.
you should now see the grub bootloders.